# SSRS: How to merge 2 header cells in the same column

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like to get the header organized this way. However, when I select 2 cells in the same column and right-click, I don't see any suggestions about merging cells. Any other way to accomplish the same thing?

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+--
|           |            | Proposed Bonus    |
|   Name    |   Bureau   +-------+-----------+--
|           |            |  (%)  |  ($)      |
+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+---
| Doe, Jane | Accounting | 3.1%  | $3,177.51 |
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Sometimes after you have added grouping it won't let you merge certain cells. Worst case is create a new table and merge those cells first then add the groupings back in.

Comment: I've done as you suggested, i.e. I've merged cells then added a table that I formatted to give the impression of the above layout. It works, but I don't know whether there's no built-in functionality for that.